# SQL - Most efficient way to set variable to value in table depending on existence of other values in same column?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm currently working on a stored procedure that, in part, returns a table based on a character code (like 'AAA' or 'XYZ'). Each row has a character code, and they're all part of the same column 'Code'. Here's the sort of algorithm I'm looking for:

```
If 'XXX' exists in the table, @variable = 'XXX' --(XXX trumps all other codes)
Else if 'YYY' exists in the table, @variable = 'YYY' --(If there's no XXX, pick YYY)
(list continues on...)
Else, @variable = ''
```

This isn't technically difficult, but I hesitate to use something like:

```
SET @variable = CASE WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 Code FROM dbo.Table WHERE Code = 'XXX') THEN 'XXX'
                     WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 Code FROM dbo.Table WHERE Code = 'YYY') THEN 'YYY'
                etc...
```

since the query looks like it would eat up a ton of resources really fast for lower priority codes.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you add sample data and desired results?  You mention returning a table of some sort, yet your sample code is only setting a variable.

Comment: Oh, I only used that as context to explain that this was a small part of a larger procedure. For this subsection, what I do want is indeed setting the variable, which goes on to be passed to some other stored procedures to retrieve some data, etc. and then finally a table is produced. It's pretty much one of the first steps in this larger procedure.

Comment: What about creating a "code" table with `CODE` and `PRIORITY` columns that you can join to and get the highest `PRIORITY` value?  It would make the SQL a lot cleaner.

Comment: I would consider it if I were managing the database, but I'm just a lowly newly employed grunt that probably shouldn't be making new tables out of the blue (which is also why this has been heavily abstracted). Also, for now, there's only 2 'code' cases and a default case. No guarantee that it'll stay small (which is what I'm worried about), but no guarantee that it'll get larger either; making a table for 2 values and their priorities would be overkill if it didn't get bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code of this form:

```
SET @variable = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 Code FROM dbo.Table WHERE Code = 'XXX') THEN 'XXX'
                      WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 Code FROM dbo.Table WHERE Code = 'YYY') THEN 'YYY'
                      . . . .
                 END);
```

Should be fine, assuming you have an index on `dbo.Table(code)`.

Comment: There is indeed a Unique Nonclustered Index on the column that contains the codes (along with some other columns). Should be fine then?

Comment: @RBeaulieu . . . I think so.  Each is an index lookup which should be quite fast.